# Pivot Table SQL Server Nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT oldName into #tmpProc  from(
SELECT DISTINCT p.OldmbleAI,p.ProductNo, 
    FROM Comidas c
    ) AS tb
    WHERE oldname<>''

SELECT * FROM  #tmpProc
PIVOT( min(#tmpProc.oldname)
for #tmpProc.oldname in ([1],[2],[3],[4]))as pvTable
```

Result:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want put the `productNo` into columns `[1],[2]` etc , i cant,  i tried with

Comment: Sample data would really help -- *as a text table in the question*.

Comment: Please add the definition of `#tmpProc` and insert statements of sample data.

Comment: i was edited the answer with the sample data

Comment: @GordonLinoff example data edited

Comment: That's not sample data, that's a picture of your data after your failed attempt. We need to know what your data looks like *before* your failed attempt and it needs to be `text`, not an image. We can't use an image.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the source query in a sub-query.
With only the required colums.

A `MAX` works for strings also.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Subensamble, Proceso#, ProductNo 
    FROM #tmpProc
) AS Src
PIVOT(
    MAX(ProductNo) 
    FOR Proceso# IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) AS Pvt;
```

Answer (score 1):

## The following are a few suggestions on how I'd write the SQL

**Source Control**

If you don't already have a [database project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272677(v=vs.103)), create one in [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). Then check it in to source control. [Microsoft Azure DevOps Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/devops/) is free & private for teams of 5 or less (this is per project, so 5 developers per project). Then you'll be able to track changes you make to your stored procedures, views, tables, etc.

**Formatting**

I would download the following tool for SSMS and Visual Studio, [Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TaoKlerks.PoorMansT-SqlFormatterSSMSVSExtension) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter). I use it when I have to edit other developer's code. It's a great way to standardize your SQL. I find it does most of the formatting for me, but I'll still make a few changes after.

Here are the settings I used:

[image: screenshot]

**Commas**

I would put the commas in front to clearly define new columns. Versus code wrapped in multiple lines. It also makes trouble-shooting code easier.

**Common Table Expressions (CTE)**

[CTE's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your SQL help with documentation. The expression name can then let other developers know why you used that expression e.g. `current_suppliers` or `active_projects`.

**Schema Names**

Always reference the schema when selecting an object e.g. `[dbo].[SalesTable]`.

**Estimated Execution Plan**

It's a good idea to check the [Estimated Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017). The shortcut in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. You can even run 2 queries in the same tab to compare the plans.

- Also check out the book [*Clean Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882). It will change the way you think about naming conventions.

---

**Revised SQL**

```
WITH
test_data
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
    ( '1AD-SA02096', '1AD-SA02096E-2', 2)
   , ( '1AD-SA02096', '1AD-SA02096E-1', 3)
   ) tbl ([Subensamble], [ProductNo], [Proceso]) 
)
SELECT
    [Subensamble]
   , [1]
   , [2]
   , [3]
   , [4]
FROM
   test_data AS src 
      PIVOT  
      (  
      MAX([ProductNo])  
      FOR [Proceso] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
   ) AS pvt;
```

**Results**

[image: screenshot]